# How to check if some service on android is unavailable?

Tags: android, service, vpn

I discovered, that on some devices [VPNService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) is unavailable even if they has proper android version (4.0 or grater). Is there a way to check is some serivce is realy available on device?

The tricky part is, that on some devices exception is thrown after calling establish() method, but on other devices this methods works fine, but app crashes after trying to open confirmation window. So resolution can not relay on check whether establish() throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the OpenVPN for Android app. I had to deal with these bugs too. The first one is easy. It will throw a ActivityNotFoundException. If you want to check this before you probably can check if the Activity mentioned in the intent exists.

http://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/source/browse/src/de/blinkt/openvpn/LaunchVPN.java?name=v0.5.28#380

The establish() problem is much harder to get. I use a catch all exception. In almost all cases the /dev/tun device does not exist or has the wrong rights. Checking for this will work but the implementation can change and headset vendor can theoretically roll their own implementation. It is like asking the OS: "Are you buggy?" and expecting a right answer ...

http://code.google.com/p/ics-openvpn/source/browse/src/de/blinkt/openvpn/OpenVpnService.java?name=v0.5.28#351